# Datatables sorting more rows with same value

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

please I need your help with sorting in DataTables.

Imagine this table (this is table in HTML):

```
Date                  Formatted date        Name
2017-02-02 08:00:00   2.2.2017 08:00        John Smith
2017-02-02 08:00:00   2.2.2017 08:00        Petr Novak
2017-02-03 08:00:00   2.3.2017 08:00        Steven Smith
```

But if I apply datatables, result is like this:

```
Date (Sorting)        Formatted date        Name
2017-02-02 08:00:00   2.2.2017 08:00        Petr Novak
2017-02-02 08:00:00   2.2.2017 08:00        John Smith
2017-02-03 08:00:00   2.3.2017 08:00        Steven Smith
```

What I want to say is that if I sort by column which has rows with same values (2x 2017-02-02 08:00:00), this rows aren't in order in which I put them into html (first John Smith, second Petr Novak) but they are inverse (first Petr Novak, second John Smith).
Do you have any solution how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort records by date AND name, use [`columns.orderData`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) option.

See [Multi-column ordering example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) for code and demonstration.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1020/) kindly provided by [@davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478).

Comment: No, I don't want to sort by name.
I just want to let order for rows with same value - as I wrote, first I put John Smith with date and then Petr Novak with same date but then this 2 rows are switched...

Comment: @JanKožušník, gyrocode is absolutely right, perhaps you didnt follow the links and read the instructions? Simply add `orderData: [ 0, 2 ]`  to your column definition **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1020/**